# Copy command line arg to a variable C

Tags: c, variables, command-line-arguments

How can I copy a command line arg to a variable in `c`? If was to do the following.

`myprog "Hello, world!"`

I want to store the value of the parameter in a `char` variable. Not sure if I am going in the right direction here.

*Assuming only 1 parameter will be passed in always.*

```
int main (int argc, char  *argv[]){

  int len;
  len=strlen(argv[1]);
  char *array;

  array= malloc((len +1) * sizeof(char));
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=len;i++){

    // This does not work... am a little lost
    array[i]=*(argv+1)[i];

  }
...
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: The easy way is `char* saved_arg = strdup(argv[1]);`. Do yourself a favor and learn the basic standard library functions.

Comment: By the way, you probably wanted to write `argv[1][i]` or `(*(argv+1))[i]`

Comment: Don't assume that you'll be passed one parameter; check that you were passed (at least) one parameter before using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not planning to manipulate the argument, you could just copy the pointer, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* array;

    array = argv[1];

    ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can make a copy of the string like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* array;

    array = strdup(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Just a doubt, why didnt we use strcpy here instead of strdup? Would the output have been different? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an operator-precedence issue. Code `*(argv+1)[i]` is evaluated as `*((argv+1)[i])` when what you want is `(*(argv+1))[i]`. You are better off to just use `argv[i][0]`.

Evaluating as `*((argv+1)[i])` is equivalent to `*(*((argv+1)+i))` which is `*(*(argv+1+i))` which is `*(argv[i+1])` which is trying to pick out the first character of arguments # 1 through len+1.

In general, your code is more clear if you use subscripts instead of pointer arithmetic. Unnecessary pointer arithmetic is best left to puzzle questions in job interviews.